# Keras Custom Layer 2D input -> 2D output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, keras-layer

I have an 2D input (or 3D if one consider the number of samples) and I want to apply a keras layer that would take this input and outputs another 2D matrix. So, for example, if I have an input with size (ExV), the learning weight matrix would be (SxE) and the output (SxV). Can I do this with Dense layer?

**EDIT** (Nassim request):

The first layer is doing nothing. It's just to give an input to Lambda layer:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Reshape,Lambda
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model

input_sample = [
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]]
,[[21,22,23,24,25],[26,27,28,29,30],[31,32,33,34,35],[36,37,38,39,40]]
,[[41,42,43,44,45],[46,47,48,49,50],[51,52,53,54,55],[56,57,58,59,60]]
]


model = Sequential()
model.add(Reshape((4,5), input_shape=(4,5)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.transpose(x)))
intermediate_layer_model = Model(input=model.input,output=model.layers[0].output)
print "First layer:"
print intermediate_layer_model.predict(input_sample)
print ""
print "Second layer:"
intermediate_layer_model = Model(input=model.input,output=model.layers[1].output)
print intermediate_layer_model.predict(input_sample)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. Is it 2D because it's a sequence? Then LSTM are made for that and will return a sequence if desired size if you set return_sequence=True.

CNN's can also work on 2D inputs and will output something of variable size depending on the number of kernels you use.

Otherwise you can reshape it to a (E x V, ) 1D tensor, use a Dense layer with SxV dimension and reshape the output to a (S,V) 2D tensor...

I can not help you more, we need to know your usecase :-) there are too many possibilities with neural networks.

**EDIT :**

You can use TimeDistributed(Dense(S)).
If your input has a shape (E,V), you reshape to (V,E) to have V as the "time dimension". Then you apply TimeDistributed(Dense(S)) which will be a dense layer with weights (ExS), the output will have the shape (V,S) so you can reshape it to (S,V).

Does that make what you want ? The TimeDistributed() layer will apply the same Dense(S) layer to every V lines of your input with shared weights.

**EDIT 2:**

After looking at the code of keras backend, it turns out that to use the transpose from tensorflow with 'permutation patterns' option available, you need to use K.permute_dimensions(x,pattern). The batch dimension must be included. In your case :

```
Lambda(lambda x: K.permute_dimensions(x,[0,2,1]))
```

K.transpose(x) uses the same function internally (for tf backend) but permutations is set to the default value which is [n,n-1,...,0].

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is not a sequence, and so can't use LSTM. I also thought about CNN, but then it doesn't learn a weight (SxE)  matrix, because it will share the  weights. The possibility to reshape don't work either, because is the opposite, i.e., all weights will be applied simultaneously for each neuron.

Comment: Edited with another proposition :)

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it! It's a nice and clever way to do it. :)

Comment: Additional note: the transpose calculation must not be done with Keras Reshape Layer, because the layer does not make the transpose.

Comment: You can then make a custom layer (lambda) using the backend : K.transpose()

Comment: Yes, but I think that then it tries to transpose the full batch. For example, I was getting this error: 
"ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,4,3) into shape (3,4,3)"
This is for a test case with a sequence of size 3, each with with dimensions 4x5

Comment: Can you post your code into your question? With the example and what you've tried with K.transpose() and the full error

Comment: I eddied the main question.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably autoencoder.

https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html